# Underline and center headings

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, titlesec, starred-version, text-decorations

For a paper I have to make my LaTeX document guideline conforming. Many of you will already guess now that this means dirty work by violating virtually all possible typography standards.

My biggest problem is concerning *section* headings. They have to be:

- Capitalized
- Underlined
- Centered
- Have roman numerals
- **The bibliography should not be appended a section number.**

I tried to achieve this using the `sectsty` package and since that did not work out gave the `titlesec` package a shot, both with and without the `ulem` package.
However, no combination worked. The problem occurs in any way when you give the option `underlined`.

Here is a minimal example with the `sectsty` package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

%% ADJUSTMENTS FOR IAC
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Get stupid underlining for headings right
\usepackage[]{ulem}

%% Change heading style
\usepackage{sectsty}
    \sectionfont{\MakeUppercase\rmfamily\center\underline}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test Section}
\end{document}
```

How can I make those headings conform to the rules? Would it probably even be the easiest way to manually write the headings, without a command at all?

Comment: Are you allowed to fiddle with the sectioning command and/or include packages as needed? I know that some journal restrict the use of external packages, or have a list of "approved packages" that you can use.

Comment: Yes I am, all I have to do is hand in a PDF.

Comment: I think this question deserves the [tag:starred-version] tag. I had to drop another tag and chose [tag:sectsty].

Comment: Quoting from page 5 of the manual of the `sectsty` package: "The documentation for this package is written with the standard LATEX classes in mind, so might not [tee] up exactly to the KOMA-script classes. Despite that, and despite differences in behaviour when things go wrong, sectsty should work as expected with the KOMA-script classes." I guess you're encountering an instance when this isn't the case...

Comment: On second thought, this question is also not specific to [tag:koma-script], but shows how to solve a [tag:horizontal-alignment] problem.

Comment: @Ingo Gerth: I've updated my answer. A simple change in the position of the `\thesection` command in the arguments of `\titleformat` gives now the desired result, using only one `\titleformat` command.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Building on Gonzalo's answer: Use the `numberless` key to define the starred version of `\section`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\sffamily\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}{\uline{\thesection\hspace*{ 1em}\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\sffamily\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}{\uline{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{A01} A. Author. \emph{Alpha}. 2001.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Ingo: Note that upvoting, accepting, and awarding bounty all have to be done separately.

Comment: I'm sorry, must have forgotten that in a rush :).

Comment: A rush of happiness, I presume. :-)

Comment: @Ingo: Thanks for awarding the bounty to me, but I think that Gonzalo Medina's latest edit makes his answer the better one, and that you should accept it instead of mine.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I just get the error "! Argument of \@xdblarg has an extra }."

Comment: @Marcin I tested my example again right now, and it works. Try to delete all auxiliary files before compiling.

Comment: @lockstep Now it just says `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` The begin document is there.

Comment: Note: You should not longer use `titlesec` with `scrartcl`.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a simple solution using the `ulem` package and the `explicit` option for `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\sffamily\bfseries\filcenter}{\uline{\thesection\hspace*{ 1em}}}{0em}{\uline{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{A01} A. Author. \emph{Alpha}. 2001.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and clean solution - the `explicit` package option is the key here.

Comment: I thank you very much, Gonzalo! Whatever it takes to comply with those ... nice ... requirements.

Comment: One more question, though. Why do prefer `titlesec` over `sectsty`?

Comment: @Ingo Gerth: with the `explicit` option for `titlesec` one has access to the title as a parameter, so it is easy to apply `\ulem` to it.

Comment: Gonzalo, thank you very much again. However, it so happens that this causes the bibliography to have a section number, whereas it should not. You can easily try this out. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Added a bounty because this is pretty important to me!

Comment: @Ingo Gerth: see my updated answer.

Comment: @lockstep: your answer also solves the OP's problem ;-)

Comment: Note: You should not longer use `titlesec` with `scrartcl`.

Answer (score 3):

Because both the answer provided by Gonzalo and the answer provided by lockstep don't work well, here is mine. This might be grave diggin' because the original question is 5 years old but it shows up at the top of google. The problem with both of their solutions is, that the entire caption is in one hbox. Because of that long captions do not work. They get an overfull hbox.
My solution only addresses that and doesn't address the rest of the question (capitalized captions and stuff). In addition my solution does not work with KOMA-script-classes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\underline}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalsize\bfseries\raggedright}
   {\llap{\makebox[3mm][l]{\thesection}}}
   {0em}
   {}

\begin{document}
\section{This is a really long section heading and I'm proud of it}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

EDIT: For a KOMA compatible way to allow line breakable underlined headings see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256654/117050).

EDIT2: If you use KOMA and hyperref, the above provided link doesn't work if you use `\tableofcontents` or similar, so you might take a look at [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374493/117050).

Comment: There seems to be no need for `\makebox[3mm][l]` here.

Comment: Note: You should not longer use `titlesec` with `scrartcl`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I know and I don't. There is no `scrartcl` in my answer, it clearly states, that it is not compatible with KOMA and the EDIT links to an answer which is and doesn't use `titlesec`, so what is the problem?

Comment: My comment was, because the example in the question has used `scrartcl`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke and I linked to a working answer which uses KOMA-classes and does the job better than all the answers provided here (including yours). Well the answer in the link suffers its own problems (hyperref compatibility). I'll edit my answer providing a link to another answer incorporating hyperref.

Answer (score 3):

For several years usage of `titlesec` with KOMA-Script classes is not recommended or only recommended if you do not need extended headings features of the KOMA-Script classes. So I would recommend to use `scrartcl`'s interface to change the section heading:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[]{ulem}
\usepackage{microtype}% to add letter spacing

\addtokomafont{section}{\rmfamily\lsstyle}% use roman instead of sans serif
                                % but letter spaceing
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{% do it only, for section level
    \centering \uline{#3\MakeUppercase{#4}}%
  }{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}% otherwise use the default
  }%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}
\blindtext
\section*{Test Section}
\blindtext
\addsec{Test Section}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I've used `\addtokomafont` to change the font of the heading and also to add some automatic letter spacing (because of the upper case typesetting) and redefined `\sectionlinesformat` to add `\MakeUppercase`, `\uline` and `\centering`. If not only the section but also sub-section etc. titles should be centered. You could get centering also using `\let\raggedsection\centering`. Nevertheless, `\sectionlinesformat` should be used for `\MakeUppercase` and `\uline` in that case too.

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\font\uc="Times New Roman" at 12pt
\begin{center}
\underbar{\uc{But it may be enough to get you started, at least. }}
\end{center}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{A01} A. Author. \emph{Alpha}. 2011.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You forgot to load `lipsum` (I did it in my edit) and loaded some irrelevant packages (I deleted them). Notice that your solution doesn't number the sections and doesn't allow for labelling. You should also mention (although `fontspec` makes it clear) that your code needs to be run with `xelatex`.

Comment: And this code does not prevent page breaks between the pseudo heading an the text.