# Centering a section

Tags: sections-paragraphs

When creating a table of contents, by using the book style, how do you center a section?

I tried:

```
\begin{center}
\section{name of section}
\end{center}
```

but it gave me an error.

Comment: Related (duplicate?) questions: [Section Heading Centering problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8546) and [Section Heading Centering problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8546).

Comment: This is most easily done with the `titlesec` package.

Comment: Sorry I pasted two identical links.  The second question I had in mind is [Underline and center headings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26878).

Comment: Doesn't matter, I already solved my problem, thank you.