# Creating new entry style in tocbasic

Tags: koma-script, tocbasic

I want to customize my table of contents and lists of figures and tables using `tocbasic`. I originally did these customizations with `tocloft`. I managed to get almost everything done. However there are 2 issues remaining:

1. Creating standalone styles instead of using the options to `tocline`
2. It seems the `dynnumwidth` and `numsep` options don't have any effect

I'd like to create a standalone style for each of chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, figure, and table. I know there is `\CloneTOCEntryStyle{tocline}{chapter}` but I don't think it is possible to clone it with the options set.

Below is a complete MWE.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[left=25mm,right=25mm,top=8.4mm,bottom=10.7mm%
    ,includeheadfoot,headsep=15.4mm,marginparwidth=18mm,marginparsep=4mm]%
    {geometry}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\skillmon@chapter@dotfill}{%
    \def\@dotsep{0.072}\TOCLineLeaderFill[\textbf{.}]%
}
\newcommand*{\skillmon@section@dotfill}{%
    \def\@dotsep{0.072}\TOCLineLeaderFill%
}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    ,beforeskip=1.15em plus 1pt%
    ,dynnumwidth=true% commenting out this doesn't change anything
    ,numsep=5pt% changing this to e.g. -5pt doesn't change anything
    ,linefill=\skillmon@chapter@dotfill%
    ,entryformat=\textbf%
    ,indent=0pt%
    ,level=0%
    ,pagenumberbox=\relax%
]{tocline}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    ,beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt%
    ,dynnumwidth=true%
    ,numsep=5pt%
    ,linefill=\skillmon@section@dotfill%
    ,indent=1.3em%
    ,pagenumberbox=\relax%
]{tocline}{section}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    ,beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt%
    ,dynnumwidth=true%
    ,numsep=5pt%
    ,linefill=\skillmon@section@dotfill%
    ,indent=3.38em%
    ,pagenumberbox=\relax%
]{tocline}{subsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    ,beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt%
    ,dynnumwidth=true%
    ,numsep=5pt%
    ,linefill=\skillmon@section@dotfill%
    ,indent=6.38em%
    ,pagenumberbox=\relax%
]{tocline}{subsubsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    ,beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt%
    ,dynnumwidth=true%
    ,numsep=5pt%
    ,linefill=\skillmon@section@dotfill%
    ,indent=1.5em%
    ,pagenumberbox=\relax%
]{tocline}{table}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    ,beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt%
    ,dynnumwidth=true%
    ,numsep=5pt%
    ,linefill=\skillmon@section@dotfill%
    ,indent=1.5em%
    ,pagenumberbox=\relax%
]{tocline}{figure}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\blinddocument
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[1.1]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[1.2]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[1.1]{example of figure}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[1.2]{example of figure}
\blinddocument
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[2.1]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[2.2]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[2.1]{example of figure}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[2.2]{example of figure}
\blinddocument
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[3.1]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[3.2]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[3.1]{example of figure}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[3.2]{example of figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's `tocbasic`? KOMA?

Comment: @cfr `tocbasic` is the package KOMA-script uses to format all its lists. It is loaded automatically if you use a KOMA-class (see also the description of the [`tocbasic`-tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/tocbasic/info)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `dynnumwidth=true` the value of `numwidth` is not completly ignored (unlike the documentation). Instead it works as minimum width of the entry numbers including `numsep`. That means the used width for the entry numbers is at least `numwidth`, but it will be adjusted if there are numbers which need space wider than `numwidth`. So the effect of `dynumwidth=true` and/or changes of `numsep` is only visible, if the needed space is wider than `numwidth`. I think the documentation for `tocdynnumwidth` have to be changed (or it is a bug of `tocbasic`).

If you add `numwidth=0pt` to the settings for each TOC style entry, then `dynnumwidth` and `numsep` have an effect even if there are only short entry numbers.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}
%\documentclass[11pt]{report}
%\usepackage{tocbasic}% with a KOMA-Script class do not load explicitly

\usepackage[left=25mm,right=25mm,top=8.4mm,bottom=10.7mm%
    ,includeheadfoot,headsep=15.4mm,marginparwidth=18mm,marginparsep=4mm]%
    {geometry}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\def\@dotsep{0.072}
\newcommand*{\skillmon@chapter@dotfill}{%
    \TOCLineLeaderFill[\textbf{.}]%
}
\newcommand*{\skillmon@section@dotfill}{%
    \TOCLineLeaderFill%
}
\newcommand*\skillmon@pagenumberbox[1]{\makebox{#1}}
\newcommand*\skillmon@numsep{0pt}% <- adjust this to set the minimum space between the numbers and the titles

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    ,beforeskip=1.15em plus 1pt%
    ,dynnumwidth=true%
    ,numwidth=0pt,% <- added
    ,numsep=\skillmon@numsep%
    ,linefill=\skillmon@chapter@dotfill%
    ,entryformat=\textbf%
    ,indent=0pt%
    ,level=0%
    ,pagenumberbox=\skillmon@pagenumberbox%
]{tocline}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    ,beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt%
    ,dynnumwidth=true%
    ,numwidth=0pt,% <- added
    ,numsep=\skillmon@numsep%
    ,linefill=\skillmon@section@dotfill%
    ,indent=1.3em%
    ,pagenumberbox=\skillmon@pagenumberbox%
]{tocline}{section}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    ,beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt%
    ,dynnumwidth=true%
    ,numwidth=0pt,% <- added
    ,numsep=\skillmon@numsep%
    ,linefill=\skillmon@section@dotfill%
    ,indent=3.38em%
    ,pagenumberbox=\skillmon@pagenumberbox%
]{tocline}{subsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    ,beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt%
    ,dynnumwidth=true%
    ,numwidth=0pt,% <- added
    ,numsep=\skillmon@numsep%
    ,linefill=\skillmon@section@dotfill%
    ,indent=6.38em%
    ,pagenumberbox=\skillmon@pagenumberbox%
]{tocline}{subsubsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    ,beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt%
    ,dynnumwidth=true%
    ,numwidth=0pt,% <- added
    ,numsep=\skillmon@numsep%
    ,linefill=\skillmon@section@dotfill%
    ,indent=1.5em%
    ,pagenumberbox=\relax%
]{tocline}{table}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    ,beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt%
    ,dynnumwidth=true%
    ,numwidth=0pt,% <- added
    ,numsep=\skillmon@numsep%
    ,linefill=\skillmon@section@dotfill%
    ,indent=1.5em%
    ,pagenumberbox=\skillmon@pagenumberbox%
]{tocline}{figure}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\blinddocument
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[1.1]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[1.2]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[1.1]{example of figure}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[1.2]{example of figure}
\blinddocument
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[2.1]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[2.2]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[2.1]{example of figure}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[2.2]{example of figure}
\blinddocument
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[3.1]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[3.2]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[3.1]{example of figure}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[3.2]{example of figure}
\end{document}
```

Now the value of `\skillmon@numsep` sets the minimum space between the numbers and the titles in ToC. In the example it is set to `0pt`.

Run three times to get

[image]

Note that this example will also work if you replace `scrreprt` by the standard class `report`. But then you have to load package `scrtocbasic` explicitly.

---

You are using the KOMA-Script class `scrreprt`. So it is possible to set the options for the toc entries also in the optional argument of `\RedeclareSectionCommand`, `\RedeclareSectionCommands` etc. But note there you have to add the prefix `toc` to each of these options.

Example:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,
%listof=nochaptergap% remove the chapter gap in lists like LOT or LOF
]{scrreprt}[2017/01/03]

\usepackage[left=25mm,right=25mm,top=8.4mm,bottom=10.7mm%
    ,includeheadfoot,headsep=15.4mm,marginparwidth=18mm,marginparsep=4mm]%
    {geometry}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\def\@dotsep{0.072}
\newcommand*\skillmon@pagenumberbox[1]{\makebox{#1}}
\newcommand*\skillmon@numsep{0pt}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[%
    ,tocnumwidth=0pt%
    ,tocdynnumwidth=true%
    ,tocnumsep=\skillmon@numsep%
    ,tocpagenumberbox=\skillmon@pagenumberbox%
]{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
    ,beforeskip=1.15em plus 1pt%
    ,tocentryformat=\textbf%
    ,toclinefill={\TOCLineLeaderFill[\textbf{.}]}%
]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  ,tocindent=3.38em%
]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  ,tocindent=6.38em%
]{subsubsection}


\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    ,dynnumwidth=true%
    ,numwidth=0pt%
    ,numsep=\skillmon@numsep%
    ,pagenumberbox=\skillmon@pagenumberbox%
]{tocline}{table}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    ,dynnumwidth=true%
    ,numwidth=0pt%
    ,numsep=\skillmon@numsep%
    ,pagenumberbox=\skillmon@pagenumberbox%
]{tocline}{figure}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\blinddocument
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[1.1]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[1.2]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[1.1]{example of figure}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[1.2]{example of figure}
\blinddocument
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[2.1]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[2.2]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[2.1]{example of figure}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[2.2]{example of figure}
\blinddocument
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[3.1]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[3.2]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[3.1]{example of figure}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[3.2]{example of figure}
\end{document}
```

I have removed the options with values equal to the defaults. Run three times to get the same result as above.

---

Because `\CloneTOCEntryStyle` is mentioned in the question:

`scrreprt` uses `\CloneTOCEntryStyle` to clone `tocline` to the styles `chapter` and `section` and `\TOCEntryStyleStartInitCode` to declare the initial settings for some of the options of the new styles. Then style `section` is cloned to style `default`.

So you could also do something like (warning: the example below uses **undocumented internal commands**, so it can break in the future)

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,
%listof=nochaptergap% remove the chapter gap in lists like LOT or LOF
]{scrreprt}[2017/01/03]

\usepackage[left=25mm,right=25mm,top=8.4mm,bottom=10.7mm%
    ,includeheadfoot,headsep=15.4mm,marginparwidth=18mm,marginparsep=4mm]%
    {geometry}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\def\@dotsep{0.072}

\TOCEntryStyleInitCode{default}{%
    \expandafter\renewcommand%
        \csname scr@tso@#1@numwidth\endcsname{0pt}%
    \expandafter\renewcommand%
        \csname scr@tso@#1@numsep\endcsname{0pt}%
  \expandafter\renewcommand%
      \csname scr@tso@#1@pagenumberbox\endcsname[1]{\makebox{##1}}%
}
\makeatother

\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocstyle=default,tocdynnumwidth=true]{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth=true]{default}{table}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth=true]{default}{figure}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
    ,beforeskip=1.15em plus 1pt%
    ,tocentryformat=\textbf%
    ,toclinefill={\TOCLineLeaderFill[\textbf{.}]}%
]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  ,tocindent=6.38em%
]{subsection}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\blinddocument
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[1.1]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[1.2]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[1.1]{example of figure}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[1.2]{example of figure}
\blinddocument
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[2.1]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[2.2]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[2.1]{example of figure}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[2.2]{example of figure}
\blinddocument
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[3.1]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lot}{table}[3.2]{example of table}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[3.1]{example of figure}
\addxcontentsline{lof}{figure}[3.2]{example of figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the explanation why `dynnumwidth` doesn't work. If there is the possibility that the method breaks in the future, I think I'll just use my code with the tweaks you provided. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. The first example (without internal commands) should work in the future. The second if only shown because you have mentioned `\CloneTOCEntryStyle` in the question.

Comment: If it sets the minimum width, shouldn't it have an effect only if the numbers are shorter? If it has an effect only if they are longer, wouldn't that mean it is setting their maximum width?

Comment: @esdd I had to drop the usage of `\RedeclareSectionCommands`, because I have to use `titlesec` for some formattings of headings. But now everything is working in my code.

Comment: @cfr `numwidth` sets a minimum width which is reserved for the numbers. If the numbers are longer than that and `dynnumwidth=false` they will overlap with the entries.

Comment: @cfr I have changed my answer a bit. Maybe it is now clearer.

Comment: @Skillmon The usage of `titlesec` with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended. It breaks some KOMA features. Maybe it can replaced by redefinitions of `\chapterlinesformat` etc.

Comment: @Skillmon That sounds like a maximum width to me i.e. no more space is permitted, so longer numbers overlap. A minimum width would create bigger boxes for shorter numbers and let longer numbers have boxes of natural width.

Comment: @esdd I know that and I would never recommend anybody to use `titlesec` with KOMA. But for my specific use case (recreating a typographically bad Word template) I found no satisfying solution without `titlesec` while still using KOMA-script so far (and the rest of it is much easier with KOMA). If you know any solution which allows underlined chapter headings which are line breakable and customizable so I can make them look like the ones I need, please let me know, because I found none (and Markus Kohm states this is bad typography so he won't support it).

Comment: @cfr *Without* option `dynnumwidth=true` the value of `numwidth` is the *fixed width* for the numbers. But if `dynnumwidth=true` is set, then `numwidth` is the minimum space used for the numbers. If at least one number is too long and would overlap the width is adjusted. If they are all shorter then `numwidth` there is more space between the numbers and titles as `numsep` and Skillmon wants to remove this white space.

Comment: @Skillmon Yes it is bad typography. Nevertheless maybe ist is possible (something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256654). But I do not know how  the chapter titles should look like.

Comment: @esdd I never found that solution (and didn't find anything in the scrguide, too). Thank you very much for that link. I'll investigate whether it works for my (really ugly) setup. Again, thank you very much!