# KOMA -- Underlined headings using `ulem` conflicts with `hyperref`

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, koma-script, ulem

I noticed, that if you underline headings with the use of `ulem` and redefining `\sectionlinesformat` (as done in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256654/117050)) does conflict with `hyperref`. The conflict only occurs on unnumbered sections, subsections and subsubsections (regardless whether they are unnumbered due to a starred version, the usage of `\addsec` or the setting of `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{<number>}`), so essentially on those macros which use `\sectionlinesformat` -- not on those which use `\chapterlinesformat` (chapters).

The error doesn't occur if you don't expand the argument of the `\headuline` macro (remove all `\expandafter`s) or if you don't use `hyperref`.
The problem is, without expanding the argument of `\headuline` the headings are not breakable.

The error message is:

```
! Extra \else.
\H@old@ssect ...empty {#5}\@@par }\endgroup \else 
                                                  \edef \@svsechd {\unexpand...
```

You can use the following MWE to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
    \setbox0\hbox{\expandafter\headuline\expandafter{#2}}% @hangfrom had no effect so I used this setup for chapters
    \usebox0\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd0}{%
        \expandafter\headuline\expandafter{#3}%
    }%
}
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #2\expandafter\headuline\expandafter{#3}}%
    {\expandafter\headuline\expandafter{#4}}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\headuline{%
    \bgroup\markoverwith{\rule[-0.42ex]{0.25ex}{1.2pt}}\ULon%
}%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is a really long chapter heading and I'm proud of it. It is so
long it needs more than one row to be printed.}
\section{This is a really long section heading and I'm proud of it. It is so
long it needs more than one row to be printed.}
\subsection{This is a really long section heading and I'm proud of it. It is so
long it needs more than one row to be printed.}
\subsubsection{This is a really long section heading and I'm proud of it. It is so
long it needs more than one row to be printed.}
\chapter*{This is a really long chapter heading and I'm proud of it. It is so
long it needs more than one row to be printed.}
\section*{This is a really long section heading and I'm proud of it. It is so
long it needs more than one row to be printed.}
\subsection*{This is a really long section heading and I'm proud of it. It is so
long it needs more than one row to be printed.}
\subsubsection*{This is a really long section heading and I'm proud of it. It is so
long it needs more than one row to be printed.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imho it is madness to use ulem in such a place -- you have not much control over the input and it can easily break. Also it looks very bad. Beside this: hyperref inserts an anchor at the begin of argument `#4` of \sectionlinesformat and so the `\expandafter` expand the wrong command.

You can try to put your `\headuline` in `\Sectionformat` instead:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
    \setbox0\hbox{\expandafter\headuline\expandafter{#2}}% @hangfrom had no effect so I used this setup for chapters
    \usebox0\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd0}{%
        \expandafter\headuline\expandafter{#3}%
    }%
}

\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #2\expandafter\headuline\expandafter{#3}}%
    {#4}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\headuline{%
    \bgroup\markoverwith{\rule[-0.42ex]{0.25ex}{1.2pt}}\ULon%
}%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\Sectionformat[2]{\headuline{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{This is a really long chapter heading and I'm proud of it. It is so
long it needs more than one row to be printed.}
\section{This is a really long section heading and I'm proud of it. It is so
long it needs more than one row to be printed.}
\subsection{This is a really long section heading and I'm proud of it. It is so
long it needs more than one row to be printed.}
\subsubsection{This is a really long section heading and I'm proud of it. It is so
long it needs more than one row to be printed.}
\chapter*{This is a really long chapter heading and I'm proud of it. It is so
long it needs more than one row to be printed.}
\section*{This is a really long section heading and I'm proud of it. It is so
long it needs more than one row to be printed.}
\subsection*{This is a really long section heading and I'm proud of it. It is so
long it needs more than one row to be printed.}
\subsubsection*{This is a really long section heading and I'm proud of it. It is so
long it needs more than one row to be printed.}
\end{document}
```

[image]