# Unwanted double underline under subsection numbers

Tags: sectioning, mactex, preamble

I just updated my LaTeX distribution to MacTex 2016 and also updated all my packages with the `tlmgr update --all`-command.

After that I recompiled a project of mine and didn't believe my eyes.
My subsections, which were underlinded, are now double-underlined, but only under the numbers (-> screenshots).

I have coded them like this in the preamble, so that they are displayed in the same serif font as the text:

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\scshape}
    {\thesubsection}
    {1.5em}
    {}

\subsectionfont{\normalfont\underline}
```

If I remove `\underline` from the last line of code, both underlines disappear.

This was the document before updating:

[image: before updating]

An this is after updating:

[image: after updating]

Do you have an idea why this happened?
How can I remove the second underline?

---

#### Edit 1 - Added an MWE:

```
% -------------------------------------
% -----        PREAMBLE           -----
% -------------------------------------

% Set Document Class
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl} 


% Layout & Language Packages & Options
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{sectsty}

% Code to display subsections in the serif font
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\scshape}
    {\thesubsection}
    {1.5em}
    {}

\subsectionfont{\normalfont\underline}


% -------------------------------------
% -----        DOCUMENT           -----
% -------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}

\subsection{Test Subsection}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

It compiles to this:
[image: pdf]

Comment: Please, make a proper [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Done!

Comment: Looks like a bug in `komascript` or `sectsty` to me. In the meantime you can use `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\subsectionfont{\normalfont\uline}`.

Comment: And, by the way, I wonder if it is wise to use both `titlesec` and `sectsty` in the same document.

Comment: Using `titlesec` with KOMA-Script classes is not recommended; using `sectsty` along with `titlesec` is not recommended either. This makes two “don't do it”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Usage of package `titlesec' together(scrartcl) with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.

But if you insist on using `titlesec`, you could use the solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27337/36296 and do something like:

```
 \documentclass{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\scshape}{}{0em}{\uline{\thesubsection\hspace*{1em}#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]